# Transfer orders from another cms to magento

Tags: magento-1.7, orders

I have currently transferred all customers(over 2000) to magento 1.7 from another cms called k-ecommerce. There are nearly 5000 orders in old site. We need to transfer those orders to new magento site also.

Can anyone explain is it possible?
Is there any way to add orders to magento directly?

If anyone can guide me to do this, it would be more helpful for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the orders are kept in the table `sales_flat_order`. For each record in this table there is also a record in the `sales_flat_order_grid` with the same values, but fewer fields. The ordered items are in `sales_flat_order_item`. On the items table there is a foreign key to the orders table (`order_id`).
These are the basics.
If you also need to move invoices, the table is `sales_flat_invoice` (and, same as the orders have, an additional table with same values but fewer fields `sales_flat_invoice_grid`).
Same goes for shipments and credit notes (tables `sales_flat_shipment` and `sales_flat_creditmemo`).
The tips above are useful if you plan to migrate the orders on your won.
But you can also use some extensions for importing orders.

- http://www.commerceextensions.com/magento-dataflow-batch-import-export-orders-to-csv.html
- http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_orders_export_and_import.html

you will only need to provide a csv in the correct format. I haven't tested the extensions, I just found them 'out there'.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is there anyway to use objects without directly insert data to database? If yes, can you give an example or article that I can refer.

Comment: @cha Maybe this helps: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programmatically-create-order-in-magento/. If it doesn't you can try to mimic the actions in the controllers involved in creating an order (the backend order creation process for example)