# How to transfer WooCommerce Orders to Magento in Real Time

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, import, export, woocommerce

I would like to transfer orders I get from **WooCommerce into Magento**.  The reason is that I want to have one-click upsells/downsells and I can't find a module or anything for Magento that has this functionality.  But with `WooCommerce` there are a few plugins that enable this functionality.  So, for offers I'm promoting/advertising I could send them to my landing page and WooCommerce checkout (i.e. with the one-click upsells/downsells)  then transfer those orders automatically into Magento.

I was reading here: [API to automatically import Woocommerce orders to Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60511/api-to-automatically-import-woocommerce-orders-to-magento) and one of the commenters said one could do this "via API (REST or SOAP)"

In another post here: [Transfer orders from another cms to magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/6161/28341) one could use an extension.

What would be the simplest way to accomplish this? Seems via API would be but I don't have much understanding of how to setup the API and would most likely require professional help.

The extensions mentioned in the post above cost are a little pricey for me at this time but might be the way to go. Not sure.

Maybe a script that cron runs every couple minutes to update and transfer the orders? I would like it to be just like the order was received through the Magento checkout i.e. all customer info.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**The idea looks good but I haven't come across a readymade script like that. Performing migration manually will be safe and error-free as the one mentioned here**

**http://blog.contus.com/migrate-from-woocommerce-to-a-magento-platform.**

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need an API module to do it. Crobtab is not the best solution for your question.

*** This is my easy solution:

**1. In Magento**

First, you need to create a PHP script and put it into Magento root folder such as `order_api.php`. It will contain the code to retrieve `$_POST` data and insert them into Magento EAV database.

**2. In WooCommerce**

After that, add a hook to your WooCommerce store each time order is created:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'send_order_to_magento');
function send_order_to_magento ($order, $data) {
    /* convert data to an array then send it to this url: http://yourmagento/order_api.php */
}
```

That's all.